# How to distinguish between a oracle database installation and oracle client installation

Tags: oracle-database

hello experts,
I have a bash script to execute which when executing on a oracle database server will do things like reading some files , and populating some tables but if same is executed on a oracle client machine (client only installation) will not go into that loop. My problem is I am unable to find out how do i distinguish if its a DB server or only an oracle client installation.

My script will be running on oracle 12C and 19C. Any hints on how to distinguish this two types of installations?

Comment: Can't you just check if you can connect to a DB at the local host?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Check the `ps -e` output and see whether it contains the `Oracle DB Server Process` running. If running : It is a Server; If not running : It is currently not a Server and you could assume that it is a client, unless you have other requirements not currently listed in your Post.

Comment: @Prem, this can be server but not started.

Comment: @RomeoNinov , (1) that is why I mentioned "It is currently not a Server and you could assume that it is a client, unless you have other requirements not currently listed in your Post" and OP should reply. (2) OP wants to Distinguish between two cases "Server" & "Client", while "Server but not running" is the third case. (3) OP mentions "populating tables" which cannot happen if no Server is running. (4) If OP has to make the Script start the Server Process, then that itself is the Distinguisher : Successfully Starting the Server Process == Server, while "No Such Executable" == Client ....

Comment: @RomeoNinov , also forgot to include (5) If Server System is converted to Client System in re-use cases, but the Server Package is not uninstalled, then the Server Binary will still be found which will even be startable, but System should ideally be considered Client. In such cases, there will be some global configuration file listing the Servers & Clients and that should be taken as the source of truth .... With these things in Perspective, I suggested "looking for the Server Process or clarifying the unlisted requirements" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for one specific program `lsnrctl`. This is oracle listener. Or `oraInventory` which keep the list of installed Oracle software. Also you can search for `dbca` - database configuration assistant. And if found you have server installation.

If you have `ORACLE_HOME` set you can check the size of this directory (and subdirectories). If its more than 100MB this is server. Also `ORACLE_BASE` can be used.